# Android Material Design Date Picker: Customization

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

I am running into an issue where I am trying to implement Material Design datepicker, but by default with the following implementation I get the following:

[image: Default Material Design date picker implementation]

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar lastValidDate = Calendar.getInstance();
lastValidDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, DAYS_FROM_NOW_MAX);

ArrayList<CalendarConstraints.DateValidator> listValidators = new ArrayList<>();
listValidators.add(DateValidatorPointForward.from(today.getTimeInMillis())); // min
listValidators.add(DateValidatorPointBackward.before(lastValidDate.getTimeInMillis())); // max
CalendarConstraints.DateValidator validators = CompositeDateValidator.allOf(listValidators);

CalendarConstraints calendarConstraints = new CalendarConstraints.Builder()
  .setStart(today.getTimeInMillis())
  .setEnd(lastValidDate.getTimeInMillis())
  .setValidator(validators)
  .build();
datePickerDialog = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
  .setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraints)
  .setTheme(com.google.android.material.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material3_MaterialCalendar)
  .setSelection(today.getTimeInMillis())
  .build();
datePickerDialog.show(getParentFragmentManager(), "fragment");
```

NOTE: If theme is not set with `.setTheme`, runtime error occurs.

So, understanding that my own style needs to be set, I defined the following in my module's `styles.xml` file:

```
<style name="CustomDatePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.Material3.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/CustomDatePicker.Title</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderSelection">@style/CustomDatePicker.SelectedDate</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderToggleButton">@style/CustomDatePicker.InputTypeIcon</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarYearNavigationButton">@style/CustomDatePicker.YearSelectionMenu</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarMonthNavigationButton">@style/CustomDatePicker.MonthPagination</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarDay">@style/CustomDatePicker.Day</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarDayOfWeekLabel">@style/CustomDatePicker.Day</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderCancelButton">@style/CustomDatePicker.ActionButton</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderConfirmButton">@style/CustomDatePicker.ActionButton</item>
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">28px</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePicker.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelMedium">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePicker.SelectedDate" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_800</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.HeadlineLarge</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDatePicker.InputTypeIcon" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.MaterialCalendar.HeaderToggleButton">
        <item name="android:tint">@color/green_700</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary_surface</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.YearSelectionMenu" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_700</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/green_700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.MonthPagination" >
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_700</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/green_700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.DayOfWeek" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.DayOfWeekLabel" >
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/green_700</item>
        <item name="iconTint">@color/green_700</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.Day" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/reen_800</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.BodySmall</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Custom.ActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.Material3.MaterialCalendar.HeaderCancelButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Material3.LabelLarge</item>
    </style>
```

Along with changing `.setTheme` to `.setTheme(R.style.CustomDatePicker)`, I am getting the following:

[image]

However, I am running into the following issues that I am not sure how to fix:

1. Why does the input type toggle button's background is set to same as tint (i.e., tint is green, background should be white)? How can it be properly set?
2. Why is the selected date not showing up as set?
3. Why doesn't corner radius of the dialog not change when set?
4. Why do the stylist changes for the Cancel and OK button not apply?
5. On certain devices (e.g. Nexus 6, API 24), the Cancel and OK buttons just become magenta-colored blocks without text (see screenshot below). What is root cause and how can this be fixed?

[image]

Any help/guidance would be very much appreciated. TYIA!

NOTE: I believe we are using version 1.8.0 of the material library.